# How can I copy all contents in a richtextbox and paste to an excel sheet?

Tags: c#

I have a Form. In this form are a richtextbox with a few data in many rows (lines). I want to copy and paste all data in richtextbox in an excel sheet with a button.I can copy and paste all richtextbox data in an excel sheet but i have a problem.
data in richtextbox are there many rows (lines). When i click the button bynCopyPasteToExcel it works but all data are in cell A1
How can i copy-paste all data in richtextbox lines in excel ?

code is here :

```
private void btnCopyPasteToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application uygulama = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    uygulama.Visible = true;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook kitap = uygulama.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sayfa1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)kitap.Sheets[1];
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range alan = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sSheets.Cells[1,1];
    alan.Value2 = richTextBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: So you need every line in a different row, am I wrong?

Comment: Its what you said.Every line en a different row

Answer (score 1):

instead of assigning the entirely of the textbox to a single cell as you do above you will first want to break up the text of the rich textbox by line with something akin to:

```
string[] Values = richTextBox1.Text.Split("\n");
```

now that you have all the files in an array you will want to assign each value to a unique cell.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Values.count(); i++)
{
     sheets.cells[i,1] = Values[i-1]; 
}
```

this will iterate through all the values and add each to the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range alan =   (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sSheets.Cells[1,1];
```

if you want each line in a single row, you should change above code like this :

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= richTextBox1.Lines.Count(); i++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range alan = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sSheets.Cells[1, i];
            \\Save
        }
```

and save each line after this.